# Using a WeakReferenced listener

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

Assuming the following:

```
public interface Listener {
   public void onListen();
}

public class ActionClass {

   WeakReference<Listener> listener = null;

   public void doAction(String action, Listener listener) {
      this.listener = new WeakReference<Listener>(listener);
      doTheAction(action);
   }

   public void actionComplete() {
     if (listener != null && listener.get() != null)
          listener.onListen();

   } 
}

public class AnotherClass {
   ActionClass actioner = new ActionClass();
   void init()  {
      actioner.doAction("something", new Listener() {
          onListened() {
              Log.d("Tag", "Action complete!");
          }
      };


   }
}
```

Sorry if there are typos/syntax errors, this was more meant to be pseudo code.

Anyway, a lot of times by the time the "Action" is complete, the WeakReference to listener will be GCed, even though the instance of "AnotherClass" is still alive. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Why are you using a `WeakReference` instead of just holding on to a regular reference?

Comment: In the case of an Activity or Fragment for instance, if the GC wants to GC it, then I don't want a reference to the listener being the only thing that keeps it alive.

Comment: This means that the callback is essentially useless, since no client code can rely on its being called.

Comment: Not really. Take the instance of a Network action - maybe the user was searching and left to a different Activity before the results could come back. At this point, there's no real reason to keep the Listener alive or the Activity that held it.

Comment: You're not taking the client's perspective. No client can ever use the callback for anything important, since there's no guarantee it'll ever get any sort of response.

Comment: @chrylis Not all network communication is important.  If a user for instance does a search request and before the request is fulfilled, goes to a different activity, there's no need to hold onto a reference that keeps the Search activity alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an aside, more than as an answer, you have a bug in your code:

```
if (listener != null && listener.get() != null)
    listener.get().onListen();
```

This code contains a race conditition, since the GC could reap the reference between the time you check it for `null` and the time you call it. You need to replace it by this:

```
if(listener != null) {
    Listener l = listener.get():
    if(l != null)
        l.onListen();
}
```

This keeps any gotten listener alive by having a reference in a local variable.

Also, you should be aware that the GC may also keep the `Listener` around for much longer than your `AnotherClass` is otherwise alive, since there's no guarantee when it will be reaped, but I guess you knew that.

Comment: Great, great point.  This is sort of along the lines of `if (getView() != null) { ...... getView().findViewById(R.id.something).setVisibility(View.GONE);}`

Answer (score 6):

Let AnotherClass implements Listener or have a private instance inside. IE:

```
Listener myListener = new Listener() {
  public void onListed() {
    ....
  }
};
```

The AnotherClass reference to the listener will keep its reference alive (until you have AnotherClass references in your program)